# Data input, collect several lines as a String, but keep them in lines

Tags: java, input

This is my data to input, where @ is used as a delimiter for different months of purchase oders.

14/06/13#PSE-3478#bT/4674#1

22/06/13#EMI-6329#LR/4992#8@

08/07/13#ESE-6329#bT/4674#15

09/07/13#PNE-3456#PV/5732#2

27/07/13#EMI-6329#PA/1234#4@

I know how to deal with a single line: .scanNextLine() as a String, and then apply scanner again having that String object as an argument, but with a different delimiter to extract other information.

But what if there are several lines to collect for each month? Will it be mixed up if I will put them to the same String object? Cause they have to remain separated in the lines as they are.

The thing is that I need to apply a method .startNewMonth() after the month has finished. Any suggestions how to implement it properly?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need the at sign flag.  You could check if the dates are in the same month.

Here's what you do in psudeocode:

```
for each line
    process line
    if line ends with @
        start new month
    end if
end for
```

Comment: is there any secial method the check for a last sign?

Comment: I think I can get length of a string and check for a charAt last index, but maybe there is something better?

Comment: @ArthurV: int pos = line.lastIndexOf("@");

Comment: So, it will be like: if(line.lastIndexOf("@"))  { do.. } ?  And 'line' shound remain as it is?

Comment: @ArthurV: More like: if(line.lastIndexOf("@") > 0) { do.. } .  Line should not be changed, either in processing or in your start new month method.  You should change a copy of line, which you can do automatically by putting your processing code into methods.